How to get a data output from the power monitor IC?
I have this circuit which is using INA237 TI IC, it is main goal for safety from undesired high current surge:(sorry for the mess)


The SDA and SCL are connected to the SDA and SCL of the ATTINY 1614, however I really have no idea how to control the output, I mean as far as I know SDA and SCL are just used in order the MCU controls the INA237, but have no idea how to get data from the INA237.
I tried checking the datasheet for the INA237 however I couldn't really understand how the alert pin works or how to program it, if somebody thankfully could explain it to me.
Datasheets:

INA237: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina237.pdf
ATTINY 1614: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_2210180800_Microchip-Tech-ATTINY1614-SSN_C614832.pdf

Notes:

Battery used is 13S Lithium-Ion Battery, nominal voltage is 48 V 9000 mAh a.k.a 9 Ah
5V+ is a 5V DC Voltage came from DC-DC converter
B-OUT is the Battery pack which is equal to 48 V nominal
B-SENSE is the sensed voltage via R22 and going to the rest of the circuitry
maximum desired current for this circuit is <40A
8 and 9 are connected to the SDA and SCL of the IC to the SDA and SCL of the MCU

Please note me in the comments if I had forgotten any information.

What exactly is your question? How I²C works on an ATTINY 1614?

How does the chip spites the data out is it only from the i2C?

The MCU can both write control info/ data to the INA and read status info/data from the INA through I2C.
The MCU data sheet contains info how to use the TWI module to do what you must to both read and write data.
Basically, you simply read the voltage and current registers from the INA with the MCU over I2C protocol.
The I2C protocol specification from NxP may be helpful to find out how I2C itself works, instead of how you use a chip through I2C which is in the chip datashet, or how to make the MCU to talk I2C which is in the MCU data sheet.
The alert pin is rather irrelevant in relation to I2C, and the INA data sheet will tell how to configure the alert pin to achieve something with the MCU.

Thanks, understood. Do you have any idea about the alert pin?

@HazardousVoltage I do. It's up to you what you want to use it for or ignore it. You configure what it does via I2C. Your MCU the can use the state of pin to do something or not. It's all in the data sheet.


How does the chip spites the data out is it only from the i2C?

The chip does not spite the data out, you must read (write) the data from (to) corresponding registers via I2C protocol. Your ATTINY 1614 must have software utilities to initiate I2C transactions and get the data into your MCU.
Here is the table of registers available on the INA237:

Essentially your software makes calls to application routines that include the address of INA237 register and a place to get/put data, with byte count, or whatever. That's it. And, of course, you need to configure the IC properly.
Note that the INA237 IC is just for measurements and alerts (if some parameter goes out of preprogrammed range). It will not limit anything. To get the proper range out of this setup, you need to calculate the value of R(SHUNT) resistor correctly.

Thanks, understood. Do you have any idea about the alert pin?

@HazardousVoltage, "7.3.6 Multi-Alert Monitoring and Fault Detection
The INA237 includes a multipurpose, open-drain ALERT output pin that can be used to report multiple diagnostics or as an indicator that the ADC conversion is complete when the device is operating in both triggered and continuous conversion mode. The diagnostics listed in Table 7-1 are constantly monitored and can be reported through the ALERT pin whenever the monitored output value crosses its associated out-of-range threshold." - I think it gives a pretty good idea how it works.
